# Summation to product

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I came across the following equation that I am struggling to understand

$\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} x^{2j^2 -j}= \prod_{k\geq1} (1-x^{4k})(1+x^{2k-1})$

My attempt:

If we open the RHS, for values of $j=0,1,-1,2,-2, \dots ,$ we get,

$(1+x+x^3+x^6+x^{10}+ \cdots)$

On the other hand, the right-hand side seems completely different which is,

$(1-x^4)(1+x)(1-x^8)(1+x^3)\dots$

Any hint or reference would be a great help!!

Comment: You asked this same question (but without your attempt) about $40$ minutes earlier at [Summation equation to product eqiation](/q/4499032/602049), but then deleted it just less than a half hour ago. Please don't delete a question & then repost it. Instead, edit your earlier question with the additional details, in this case your attempt, to then try to get your question reopened.

Comment: Pretty sure what you mean is $\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} x^{2j^2 -j}= \prod_{k\geq1} (1-x^{4k})(1\color{red}{+}x^{2k-1})$

Comment: Hint. Apply Jacobi triple product : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, yes it is

Comment: @RobertZ, thanks